# Issues with unreliable RTT in python application

Tags: python, sockets, ethernet

I`m  having big issues getting a reliable response time for tcp communication between a server pc (Windows 10) and a Jetson Nano (production module, Ubuntu 18.04). In a test Python application a small message is send to the Nano device every 200ms. The application on the Jetson Nano application immediatly sends this message back to the server. No other communication is happening on the used ports (apart from some ssh).
The time from message transmitted and response received is measured on the server pc. What I expect is, due to the small message size (<=1024byte), the RTT is in the 0.5-2ms range.

What I get is an unreliable RTT for messages >=70byte:

> ```
> #Response time for message sent to Jetson Ubuntu client
> #message size is in bytes (payload)
> size:16 min: 0.45ms max: 0.84ms median: 0.48ms mean: 0.52ms
> size:32 min: 0.54ms max: 0.75ms median: 0.61ms mean: 0.62ms 
> size:64 min: 0.48ms max: 0.67ms median: 0.56ms mean: 0.56ms
> size:128 min: 0.64ms max: 247.83ms median: 40.11ms mean: 58.48ms
> size:256 min: 0.63ms max:261.75ms median: 96.22ms mean: 121.33ms
> size:512 min: 0.51ms max: 824.84ms median: 203.29ms mean: 244.38ms
> size:68 min: 0.44ms max: 0.52ms median: 0.48ms mean: 0.48ms
> size:69 min: 0.44ms max: 0.66ms median: 0.51ms mean: 0.53ms
> size:70 min: 0.53ms max: 304.98ms median: 155.83ms mean: 160.78ms
> size:71 min: 0.49ms max: 602.15ms median: 120.64ms mean: 197.52ms
> size:72 min: 0.54ms max: 509.05ms median: 132.59ms mean: 154.70ms
> ```

My code:

```
import socket
import time
import numpy as np

class MySocket():
    def __init__(self,sock=None):
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
        else:
            self.sock = sock
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    def connect(self,host,port):
        self.sock.connect((host,port))
    def listen(self,host,port):
        self.sock.bind((host, port))
        self.sock.listen(5)
    def accept(self):
        (clientsocket, address) = self.sock.accept()
        return (clientsocket, address)
    def send(self,msg):
        msglen = len(msg)
        sent = self.sock.sendall(msg)      
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
    def recv(self):
        # just assume the messages are small for the moment
        # and we receive just one chunk
        return self.sock.recv(4096) 
    def ping(self,msg):
        self.send(msg)
        recv_data = self.recv()              
        if len(msg) != len(recv_data):
            print(f'Package sizes do not match! {len(msg_b)} to {len(recv_data)}')

# Server app will send some messages with different sizes to the connected client
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myserver = MySocket()
    myserver.listen('',8754)

    while True:
        (clientsocket, address) = myserver.accept()
        myclientSocket = MySocket(clientsocket)

        #build up a list of messages with different sizes
        msg_list = []
        for k in range(4,10):
            msg = 'p'*(2**k)
            msg_b = msg.encode()
            msg_list.append(msg_b)

        # add a couple of messages with size in problematic range
        for k in range(68,73):
            msg = 'p'*(k)
            msg_b = msg.encode()
            msg_list.append(msg_b)

        # in productive environment we will probably send a message each 0.2 to 1.0sec to the client
        # to simulate this, sleep a little bit before each send 
        sleep_time = 0.2
        #send each message couple of times and measure response time
        for msg_b in msg_list:
            timings=[]
            for l in range(0,10):
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
                start_time = time.perf_counter()                
                myclientSocket.ping(msg_b)
                timings.append((time.perf_counter() - start_time)*1000)
            print(f'size:{len(msg_b)} min: {min(timings):.2f}ms max: {max(timings):.2f}ms median: {np.median(timings):.2f}ms mean: {np.mean(timings):.2f}ms')

''' 
# Client app will receive a message and send it back immediately
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myclient = MySocket()
    myclient.connect('192.168.2.134',8754)

    while True:
        msg = myclient.recv() 
        if msg is None:
            continue
        myclient.send(msg)
'''
```

What I tried so far:

- replaced client (Jetson Nano) with another Jetson Nano (same revision): same result, unreliable RTT
- replaced client (Jetson Nano) with different Ubuntu based PC, result: RTT as expected in 1-2ms for each message size
- replaced server (Windows PC) with different System, result: RTT as expected in 1-2ms for each message size
- used USB3.0-Ethernet Adapter on Jetson Nano instead of builtin Realtek Ethernet Controller, result: RTT as expected in 1-2ms for each message size

From my limited point of view it looks like the problem is following the Jetson Nano device and specifically the Ethernet Controller.

But I´m out of ideas right now. What can cause such a behaviour? Could it be somehow hardware related? 
Happy to hear about your suggestions :)

**small update:**

Did a test on a Ubuntu PC to ping Jetson Nano Device. Basically removing Windows as Server and the Python app from the equation. No other traffic on the lines for both parties.

```
ping -s 82 -c 100 192.168.2.115

90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=109 ms
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=305 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.401 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=295 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=131 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=294 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.473 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=263 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=130 ms 
90 bytes from 192.168.2.115: icmp_seq=10 ttl=64 time=260 ms
...
```

Very high deviation in latency with >=90bytes packets. Are there some settings for eth0 which could be related to this behaviour and can potentially improve latency for small messages?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds that "Windows as Server PC" and "Realtek as ethernet adapter in Client" together contribute to the issue; replace one of these and issue goes away.

Accordingly you could monitor TCP/IP traffic to verify if there's still some extra traffic or slowness going on between Windows PC and the client that might explain why Windows contributes to the slow performance: In Windows Wireshark software can snoop ethernet traffic, in Linux client tcpdump can analyse ongoing traffic.

As for the Realtek ethernet part, you could check your Realtek device driver version number and verify if any updates have been made since the Kernel version that you're using in the client system: `lsmod` command lists device drivers, `modinfo` shows information about a device driber module.